# Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 - Cmake - Mac sierra

Tags: c++, cmake, linkage, undefined-symbol

Recently I have started a new project in C++. The problem is, when I try to compile it I get a linking error. I spent the whole day today trying to debug it, but I did not really find a good solution anywhere. If someone could help with it it would be amazing. I am using a Mac Sierra.

**`parsing/methylation.h`**

```
#ifndef EPIRL_METHYLATION_H
#define EPIRL_METHYLATION_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

namespace methylation {
    struct MethLine {
        string chr;
        int coord;
        char strand;
        int methylated;
        int un_methylated;
        string context;
        string tag;
    };

    string calculateMethylationByContext(
            MethLine m_input[], int length,
            int window_start, int window_end, int threshold);

    void calculateMethylation(
        const istream &methylation_stream,
        const istream &coordinate_stream,
        const ostream &output_stream
    );
}

#endif //EPIRL_METHYLATION_H
```

**`parsing/methylation.cpp`**

```
#include "methylation.h"

namespace methylation {
    string calculateMethylationByContext(
            MethLine m_input[], int length,
            int window_start, int window_end, int threshold) {
// rest of the code ...
    }
}
```

**`main.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "parsing/methylation.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 4) {
        cout << "Invalid number of arguments..." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    char *methylation_file = argv[1];
    char *coordinate_file = argv[2];
    char *output_file = argv[3];

    ifstream methylation_file_stream(methylation_file, ios::binary);
    ifstream coordinate_file_stream(coordinate_file, ios::binary);
    ofstream output_file_stream(output_file, ios::binary);

    methylation::calculateMethylation(methylation_file_stream,
                         coordinate_file_stream, output_file_stream);
    methylation_file_stream.close();
    coordinate_file_stream.close();
    output_file_stream.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I use CLion for my coding. When I try to build it, my cmake command works fine, but when I then click 'make' I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "methylation::calculateMethylation(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [src] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/src.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/src.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

my **CMakeLists.txt** file looks like the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(src)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    parsing/methylation.cpp
    parsing/methylation.h
    main.cpp)

add_executable(src ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

When I run the cmake command, my output is this:

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/sztankatt/Documents/University/PartIII/Project/epiRL/src
```

Comment: Search *all* of your source files for the symbol.  Then verify that the source file containing the symbol is compiled *and linked*.  Also verify that the symbols is not static or private.

Comment: I don't see **definition** of the `calculateMethylation` in the code you provide; there is only *declaration* of this function in the `parsing/methylation.h`.

Comment: You're showing stuff related to `calculateMethylationByContext` , but your error is related to `calculateMethylation` . Where have you defined this function ?

Answer (score 6):

## Your `CMakeLists.txt` is fine.

As @thomas-matthews @tsyvarev @nos pointed out in their comments, your example code is missing the definition/implementation of `methylation::calculateMethylation()`. What you're seeing is the expected failure with Apple/clang in this situation.

```
❯ make
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/src.dir/parsing/methylation.cpp.o
/Users/nega/foo/parsing/methylation.cpp:8:5: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
1 warning generated.
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/src.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable src
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "methylation::calculateMethylation(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [src] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/src.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Adding a dummy implementation, or commenting out the call in your `main.cpp`, will allow `make` to complete successfully.

## Assuming you have a correct implementation

Let's assume you do have an implementation of `methylation::calculateMethylation()` in your code (maybe in another file). The fist step in debugging build errors in CMake generated Makefiles is to run with the make variable `VERBOSE` set to a true value, ie: `make VERBOSE=1`.

```
❯ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.0/bin/cmake -H/Users/nega/foo -B/Users/nega/foo/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/nega/foo/build/CMakeFiles /Users/nega/foo/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/src.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/src.dir/depend
cd /Users/nega/foo/build && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/nega/foo /Users/nega/foo /Users/nega/foo/build /Users/nega/foo/build /Users/nega/foo/build/CMakeFiles/src.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/src.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/src.dir/build
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/src.dir/parsing/methylation.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++     -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/src.dir/parsing/methylation.cpp.o -c /Users/nega/foo/parsing/methylation.cpp
/Users/nega/foo/parsing/methylation.cpp:8:5: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
1 warning generated.
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/src.dir/main.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++     -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/src.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/nega/foo/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable src
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/src.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/src.dir/parsing/methylation.cpp.o CMakeFiles/src.dir/main.cpp.o  -o src 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "methylation::calculateMethylation(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [src] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/src.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Now you can look at the link step and see if you're missing items; maybe a library, or an object file. If so, now you know to go back and add it to your `CMakeLists.txt`

## Summary

The first step in debugging unexpected build failures with CMake generated Makefiles is to run:

```
❯ make VERBOSE=1
```

This will give you insight into what CMake is doing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Double check which compiler is automatically detected by CMAKE. 
Can you post, what CMAKE tells you when you initially run CMAKE?

[This may be a hint for your problem, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223992/c-hello-world-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Comment: Hey! Just posted the output of my cmake command.

Interestingly when I copy the contents of the methylation.cpp file into the main.cpp, the code compiles without any errors. It seems that the linking doesn't work appropriately.

Comment: Can you check what happens when you try following: 
    cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++

Comment: You can try to do following: 
    target_link_libraries(src stdc++)
This should ensure that your project gets linked to the c++ standard library...

Comment: BTW: Sometimes it can be helpful to clean the CMAKE build directory (rm -rf *) before executing another cmake generation call as CMAKE sometimes keeps cached variables